# Is there a better way to say "radio signals of morse code"?

Tags: phrase-request

I am asking, because in a science-fiction setting you may need to differentiate between morse code sent telepathically and morse code sent through radio signals. Is there any way we can shorten or improve the awkward-sounding "radio signals of morse code"?

Comment: Why would a telepath need to communicate in code?  Couldn't they just send their thoughts verbatim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the usual term is **radiotelegraphy**, but that can be in Morse or binary codes.  You'll easily find phrases such as **Morse [code] by signal lamp** or **Morse [code] over the radio**, "... by blinking", or in your case "... by telepathy".

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_telegraphy) has the sentence "Today, due to more modern text transmission methods, **Morse code radiotelegraphy** for commercial use has become obsolete."

Answer (score 1):

The radio transmission method for Morse is called "carrier wave" or CW.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_wave

So you might contrast that with "thought wave" or TW.